# How can I update the style of a styled-component based on scroll position without re-rendering an array of randomly placed sibling components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I have a simple component which performs these actions:

1. Using hooks, sets state to keep track of `window.scrollY`
2. Attaches `scroll` eventListener to window to update state
3. Creates an array of 10 styled-components - each with a randomly assigned `absolute` position
4. return/renders the 10 dots *and* another styled-component - a triangle whose height is calculated using the scroll state defined in step 1.

```
const App = () => {
  // state to keep track of how many px scrolled
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(window.scrollY);
  const handleScroll = () => setScroll(window.scrollY);

  // set up listener on window to update scroll state on scroll
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  // create 10 dots with random positions
  const dots = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    dots.push(
      <Dot
        key={x}
        topValue={getRandomIntInclusive(1, 199)}
        leftValue={getRandomIntInclusive(1, 99)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {dots}
      <Triangle heightValue={scroll / 10} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### What I want to happen

When I scroll down, the only thing I want to happen is the `Triangle` components height recalculates / re-renders. The originally rendered dots will not update or change.

#### My problem

As you might guess, the dots get re-rendered every scroll event, which is not only horrible for performance, but it causes the dots to have a new random position every single scroll event.

#### My questions

1. How can I get the `Triangle` to re-render using the updated `scroll` value, but not have the `Dot` components re-render?
2. More of a secondary question: If I also wanted to update some style in the `Dot` components on scroll (color, for example), but **not** update the random `top` and `left` positions that were created on the initial Mount, how would I do that?

I can accomplish something like this quite easily with vanilla JS, but I can't quite figure out the React way.

Complete working sandbox of this issue: https://codesandbox.io/embed/hopeful-greider-jb3td

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is calculate the dots position once and save it in an array so as to not recalculate them on each and every render when the scroll position changes

You can either use `useEffect` with empty `deps` array to do that like

```
// main component
const App = () => {
  // state to keep track of how many px scrolled
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(window.scrollY);
  const handleScroll = () => setScroll(window.scrollY);
  const [posArr, setPos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const pos = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      pos.push({ topValue: getRandomIntInclusive(1, 199), leftValue: getRandomIntInclusive(1, 99)})
    }
    setPos(pos);
  }, [])
  // set up listener on window to update scroll state on scroll
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  // create 10 dots with random positions
  const dots = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    dots.push(
      <Dot
        key={x}
        topValue={posArr[x] && posArr[x].topValue}
        leftValue={posArr[x] && posArr[x].leftValue}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <br />
      <h2>Scroll to make triangle grow</h2>
      <br />
      <h4>Ideally, the dots would not rerender on scroll</h4>
      <Debug>Px scrolled: {scroll}</Debug>
      {dots}
      <Triangle heightValue={scroll / 10} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-water-r8rgm)

or initialise the state by using a **callback function to useState**

```
// main component
const App = () => {
  // state to keep track of how many px scrolled
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(window.scrollY);
  const handleScroll = () => setScroll(window.scrollY);

  // set up listener on window to update scroll state on scroll
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  const [posArr, setPos] = useState(() => {
    const pos = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      pos.push({ topValue: getRandomIntInclusive(1, 199), leftValue: getRandomIntInclusive(1, 99) })
    }
    return pos;
  });
  // create 10 dots with random positions
  const dots = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    dots.push(
      <Dot
        key={x}
        topValue={posArr[x].topValue}
        leftValue={posArr[x].leftValue}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <br />
      <h2>Scroll to make triangle grow</h2>
      <br />
      <h4>Ideally, the dots would not rerender on scroll</h4>
      <Debug>Px scrolled: {scroll}</Debug>
      {dots}
      <Triangle heightValue={scroll / 10} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-shadow-kqjsx)

Comment: Hm, I have a few concerns & questions about your answers. Firstly, it seems that the dots in both of your examples are being rendered in a diagonal line, from top left to bottom right. Meaning it is not generating proper random positions, but I can't figure out why not. Second, why do you set the values of the Dot as `posArr[x] && posArr[x].topValue`, for the first example, but not the second? And lastly, for performance, which of your two methods is preferable (`useEffect` or `setState` callback aka [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state))?

Comment: In the first case, the state is being set after the initial render whereas in the second case its being set before the render happens and hence the conditional checks are left out the second example

Comment: I see. And do you happen to know why the dots in your Working demos are being rendered in a diagonal line? Is that happening on your end?

Comment: Its kind of weird, but yes they seem to be rendered randomly in a diagonal fashion

Comment: Okay I figured out the issue, I was passing topValue to both leftValue and topValue. Updated the code in the answer

Comment: I should have noticed that also :D Thanks so much @shubham-khatri